# Grep some information from log files distributed on different nodes

Tags: linux, shell, grep

I need a grep command that auto logs in all the required nodes connected to that host using some for loop and display the result on the host screen without saving the file in the host. All I need to change every time is the grepping info and required nodes to grep.

This is what I tried:

```
for i in <Nodename>{1..5}; do
    echo $i
    ssh -q $i "cd <path>;grep '<string>' <filename>"
done
```

For example, if the node name is `ca02p3zsynh001`, then the log file name will be `<filename>.log_ca02p3zsynh001_20171204_001316.gz`. The last two fields are date time of 00 hrs 13 min and 16 sec.

Comment: Nice. Either hire someone to do it for you or paste your own attempt and we can help you correct it.

Comment: I'm using the command 
for i in <Nodename>{1..5};do echo $i;ssh -q $i "cd <path>;grep '<string>' <filename>";done

I'm doing the grep on log files, but here the file name will be changing dynamically as per the node name and time which the file was saving. If i know the date and node names and i have to search particular string in that files for whole day how can i get.For example node name will be ca02p3zsynh001 then the log file name will be <filename>.log_ca02p3zsynh001_20171204_001316.gz--->here the last two fields are date and time of 00 hrs 13 min and 16 sec.

Comment: Don't write what you've done in comments. Edit your question.

Comment: Thanks Benjamin for the help.... @klutt if you can help please do that as im new to this it takes time how to post questions and get upon it. Dont comment as to increase the number of your comments in the posts.. Once again thanks benjamin. :)

Comment: I meant no harm. I'm just teaching you how things are done here. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking and welcome to Stackoverflow. :)